# Editable spinner

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to make something like a **spinner** or **dropdown** list but with the ability to input the value manually when there is no right value on the list.

I'm trying to find some properties of spinner but no one seems to fit. Is there any posibility in kv language?

Comment: You could explain me better, maybe with a picture pointing out the behavior you expect

Comment: Imagine the situation where your spinner has 5 values, from 1 to 5, but sometimes I will need to put 7 or 9 or any other value. It should look like this:  https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-for-Adding-Custom-Value-to-Dropdown-List-Custom-Combo-Box.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic implementation using `DropDown` widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv = """
<CustomDropdown>:
    size_hint_y: None
    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
    height: 56.0
    orientation: "horizontal"

    TextInput:
        id: txt_input
        size_hint_x: 0.5

    Button:
        id: show_drop
        size_hint_x: 0.2
        text: "drop"
        on_release: root.show_dropdown()
    Button:
        id: submit_btn
        size_hint_x: 0.3
        text: "Submit"
        on_press: root.validate_txt()
"""


class CustomDropdown(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.fakeValues = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
        for val in self.fakeValues:
            btn = Button(text=val, size_hint=[0.5, None])
            btn.height = 56.0
            btn.bind(on_press=self.change_value)
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

    def change_value(self, *args):
        self.ids.txt_input.text = args[0].text
        self.hide_dropdown()

    def add_options(self, *args):
        btn = Button(text=args[0], size_hint=[0.5, None])
        btn.height = 56.0
        btn.bind(on_press=self.change_value)
        self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)


    def validate_txt(self, *args):
        curText = self.ids.txt_input.text
        if ((curText in self.fakeValues) or (curText == None) or (curText == "")):
            return
        self.fakeValues.append(curText)
        self.add_options(curText)
        self.hide_dropdown()

    def hide_dropdown(self):
        self.dropdown.dismiss()

    def show_dropdown(self, *args):
        if self.dropdown.parent:
            self.hide_dropdown()
        else:
            self.dropdown.open(self.ids.txt_input)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return CustomDropdown()

TestApp().run()
```

Before doing anything:

[image]

Showing DropDown:

[image]

Typing some custom words and submitting it:

[image]

Showing DropDown again:

[image]